# Why can't the Java compiler find symbols?

Tags: java

I have been working to resolve the following 4 errors for days.

Here is a short reproducible example:

```
import java.util.logging.Level1;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RcvThread2 implements Runnable{
    private static final int sizeBuf = 50;
    private Socket clientSock;
    private Logger logger;
    private socketAddress clientAddress;

    public RcvThread2(Socket clntSock, socketAddress clientAddress, Logger logger) {
        this.clientSock = clntSock;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.clientAddress = clientAddress;
    }

    public void run(
        try {
            InputStream ins = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outs = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            // ...
```

Why do I get these four compiler errors? How can I fix them?

```
error : cannot find symbol
import java.util.logging.Level1;

symbol: class Level1
location: package java.util.logging

error : cannot find symbol
InputStream ins = clientSocket.getInputStream();

symbol: variable clientSocket
location: class RcvThread2

error: cannot find symbol
OutputStream outs = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

symbol : variable clientSocket
location: class RcvThread2
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the line `import java.util.logging.Level1;` (that doesn't exist, I think you wanted [`import java.util.logging.Level`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)). And `socketAddress clientAddress` should be `SocketAddress clientAddress` (that's why you get the messages about undefined methods with `clientAddress`).

Comment: @Poisonshirimp You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. You should [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).